# How do I check if a division of two doubles is an integer?

Tags: c++, integer, double, division

I have two arbitrary doubles. The code should only continue if the division of one double by the other double is an integer. So I can't really cast the result to a double. I could do a normal double division and then check if the result is inside a tiny range of specified integers, but that seems pretty messy.

Does someone know a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Checks if 6/3 returns int: `double t = 6.0 / 3.0; bool isInteger = fabs(t - ((double)(int)t)) < EPSILON;` where `EPSILON` is a really small value. like `.0001`

Comment: Alternatively, use `fmod`: _i.e._ `bool isInteger = fabs(fmod(a, b)) < EPSILON;`

Comment: @Andy I recommend using the largest integer possible for this, not `int`. `int` isn't even guaranteed to represent all `float`s.

Comment: The question first asks how to determine whether the result **is** an integer. Then it mentions determining whether the result is **close to** an integer. Those are two different things. If what you actually want is to determine whether the result is close to an integer you have to decide what "close to" means.

Comment: To make it clear: I want to find out if it is an integer, but since double division are of finite precision, it is enough when the result is close to an integer (in the range of Epsilon). The answer and the comments already solving my problem.

Answer (score 3):

To test if one integer is evenly divisible by another integer, you can use `std::fmod`. `std::fmod` returns the remainder of a division. If the remainder is zero, then these numbers must be evenly divisible.

```cpp
#include <cmath>

constexpr double EPSILON = 1.0 / 1024 / 1024;

bool divisible(double dividend, double divisor) {
    return std::fabs(std::fmod(dividend, divisor)) < EPSILON;
}
```

There are situations where we can't use `std::fmod`, such as in a constexpr context though, so we can also do the math ourselves:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

constexpr bool divisible(double dividend, double divisor) {
    double quotient = dividend / divisor;
    double quotient_fraction = quotient - static_cast<intmax_t>(quotient);
    return quotient_fraction > -EPSILON && quotient_fraction < EPSILON;
}
```